# Using scope with a view partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, partial-views

I have been using a scope to present some information to show todos that have been completed and are 24 hours old

```
scope :completed, joins(:user).where(:todos => { :complete => true })
scope :logged, completed.where("todos.updated_at <= ?", 1.day.ago)
```

Using the regular todo partial

```
<%= render @user.todos.logged =>
```

However I want to present those logged items in a different partial _logged.html.erb. I just can't figure out the proper way to pass scope results to a specific partial.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to pass some variable to partial?

Comment: My partial would just look like: <%= todos.title %>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you want to render partial for each item, yo can do:

```
<%=render :partial=> 'logged', :collection=>@user.todos.logged %>
```

Or if you want to pass the whole array to one instance then you can do

```
<%=render :partial=> 'logged', :object=>@user.todos.logged %>
```

In both cases I guess your object will be called `logged`.

Assuming that your partial contains `<%= logged.title %>` you want to render for each item, so you can use the first version.

Answer (score 0):

First, to keep my conscience clean, let me say that that passing model code to your views is never a good idea. But if you insist :

```
<%= render :partial => 'some_partial',
:locals => {:some_variable => "somevalue",
:some_other_variable => some_other_variable} %>
```

Comment: could you explain why passing model code  to your view isn't a good idea?